# Правильная обработка всех исключений

Tags: c#, исключения

В методе `OnStartup` определяю следующий код:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += delegate(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args) {
//Запись в лог
                                                      };
```

Судя по документации он должен отлавливать все ранее не обработанные исключения, он срабатывает, идет запись в лог, а после этого приложение падает. Когда я запустил приложение в режиме отладки и сгенерировал исключение, оно вызвало обработчик, но после этого в Visual Studio появился помощник исключения, как будто исключение возникло без какой-либо обработки.

Что я делаю не так?

---

UDP. Как модифицировать код так, что-бы не только получать уведомление об исключениях, но еще их перехватывать?

Comment: [`Это событие предоставляет уведомление о неперехваченных исключениях. Он позволяет приложению регистрировать сведения об исключении до того, как системный обработчик по умолчанию сообщит пользователю об исключении и завершит работу приложения.`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netframework-4.8) главное слово тут - уведомление, а не перехват.

Comment: судя по `OnStartup` вам это для сервиса надо? .NET core?

Comment: @tym32167 хм, ясно. Как тогда модифицировать код, что-бы эта конструкция выполняла роль перехвата?

Comment: @rdorn нет, это WPF приложение, просто оно запускается подобным образом.

Comment: [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: [Globally catch exceptions in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/793100/312041)

Comment: [#](https://github.com/Athari/Alba.Framework/blob/master/Alba.Framework/Diagnostics/UnhandledExceptionsHandler.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно перехватывать необработанные исключения на разных уровнях:

1. [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) - перехватывает из всех потоков в приложении.
   Исключение нельзя обработать, можно только "усыпить" поток навсегда, для предотвращения падения.
2. [`Dispatcher.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexception.aspx) - перехватывает из одного конкретного потока диспетчера UI.
   Исключение можно обработать и не дать приложению упасть.
3. [`Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) - перехватывает из потока диспетчера UI *main* в приложении WPF.
   Исключение можно обработать и не дать приложению упасть.
4. [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx) - перехватывает в каждом AppDomain, который использует планировщик задач для асинхронных операций.
   Исключение можно обработать и не дать приложению упасть.

Выбор между № 2 и № 3 зависит от того, используете ли вы более одного потока WPF. Это довольно экзотическая ситуация, и если вы не уверены, так это или нет, то, скорее всего, нет.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472562/8361539)

Comment: первый пункт из ответа использован в вопросе, и судя по вопросу он НЕ перехватывает :) в том виде в котором тебе было нужно, ты уверен, что остальные описанные методы делают то, что ты думаешь?

Comment: @Grundy дополнил ответ, теперь уверен)